# EXC_BAD_ACCESS why is my object being deallocated?

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode5

I'm trying to populate an NSOutlineView with some data. I've created a class to wrap around the data.

(I'm using ARC, and using xcode 5.0.2)

the .h file:

```
@interface OutlineDataSource : NSObject <NSOutlineViewDataSource>{
    NSArray *theData;
}

- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray*)array;
@end
```

the .m file

```
@implementation OutlineDataSource
- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array{
    self = [super init];
    theData = array;
    return self;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item{
    return [theData objectAtIndex:index];
}

...some other mandatory methods here...

@end
```

Then in my `awakeFromNib`, inside an AppController class, I use it like so:

```
...
NSArray *theArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Foo", @"Bar", nil];
OutlineDataSource *data = [[OutlineDataSource alloc]initWithArray:theArray];
[teachersSelectOutline setDataSource:data];//the name of the NSOutlineView is "teachersSelectOutline"
...
```

The application terminates with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=bla bla bla)

I turned on zombies and then profiled it and it looks like the offending line is the return statement in:

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item{
    return [theData objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

The output from the profiler in zombie mode is:
"An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'OutlineDataSource' object (zombie) at address: bla bla bla"

and the console output if I run it with zombies on, but don't profile it is:
"[OutlineDataSource outlineView:child:ofItem:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xblablabla"

Two other relevant pieces of information:

1) If, instead of using my `initWithArray` method, I use a basic init method where I just initialize `theData` to an empty array, the error goes away and the application runs just fine.

2) If I implement all the exact same code inside the AppController class, the error also goes away, and the application runs fine.

So, clearly my `OutlineSourceData data` object is getting its reference count decreased to zero and being deallocated. Where is this happening, and how can I stop it?

(Or, am I missing something else?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just retain your array after initialize.

Comment: Can't call `retain` since I'm using ARC, @utkalpatel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely experiencing the crash because the `OutlineSourceData` instance is being deallocated as expected.  You create the instance and assign it to your `NSOutlineView` but the outline view only keeps a weak reference to the data source.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOutlineView/setDataSource%3a) of the `setDataSource:` methodd *"The receiver maintains a weak reference to the data source"*

Make the `OutlineSourceData` an ivar on your `AppController` class instead of local to the `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: Bah! You and your fancy "documentation".

Comment: So, I had actually read that line in the docs severel times. The problem was that I'm coming from Java, which doesn't care two sh*ts about references, so I didn't pay close attention when it said "weak reference".

Comment: It's one of the ways that ARC obscures things a little.  In the days of reference counted memory management, these sorts of errors were easier to spot.